# Is it possible to detect when a reference property has changed on an entity in EF6?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

This seems to be a common problem but I cannot find any answer that makes sense to me.

I want to create an Audit system in an app using EF6. Detectng changes in simple properties is not a problem and creating an audit entry with the original values in just before the new values are saved is fine.

However I also need to track changes to reference properties, i.e. The country (which links to a different entity) has changed.

dbChangeTracker does not pick these changes up and even if it did there seems to be no way of getting at the original value.

Some people point in the direction of ObjectContext for a solution, but I cannot see how that will help. Any help?

Other people seem to indicate that I should put the FK property explicitly on the Entity, i.e. Country_Id.

Is that the solution?

All help greatly appreciated.

Cheers Mike

Comment: The change tracker definitely knows about the change, otherwise it could not generate the necessary SQL statements to update the database.

Comment: @Daniel you would have thought so and I am sure that somewhere beneath the hood, something does indeed know about it. However These changes do not show up in the ChangeTracker Entries list and hence I cannot see a way of detecting them.

Comment: Depending on your needs, foreign key properties may not be sufficient. If your navigation property is set to a newly added entity, and that entity uses a server-generated identity value, the value will not be known until the saving has completed.

Comment: You might be able to use the `RelationshipManager` to find the right `EntityReference`, and then subscribe to its `AssociationChanged` event.

Comment: If i wouldn't find a solution to this i'd probably go about it by having all entities derive from a common object, mark desired properties with an attribute, override the DbContext SaveChanges, log modifications into a table with timestamp. That would enable to look up anything you want. Then again i haven't had a look into an intended solution for such a thing. Just throwing this idea at you. Someone suggested interceptors if you're using 6.1. That's pretty much what i'm describing. Only a manual approach

Answer (score 2):

Implement a method for retrieving metadata information about certain property of EntityObject:

```
private static EdmMember GetEdmMember<TEntity>(this ObjectContext context, TEntity entityContainer, string propertyName)
 {
    EdmMember edmMember = null;
    EntityType entityType = context.MetadataWorkspace.GetItem<EntityType>(entityContainer.GetType().FullName, DataSpace.CSpace);
    IEnumerable<EdmMember> edmMembers = entityType.MetadataProperties.First(p => p.Name == "Members").Value as IEnumerable<EdmMember>;
    edmMember = edmMembers.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Name == propertyName);
    if (edmMember == null)
        throw new ArgumentException(
                            string.Format("Cannot find property metadata: property '{0}' in '{1}' entity object", propertyName, entityType.Name));
    return edmMember;
}
```

The `MetadataWorkspace` class is a central runtime API that you can use to interact with the Entity Data Model (EDM) metadata in the context of an application. For more information, see 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387116%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Next, implement the `IsPropertyChanged` method like this:

```
public static bool IsPropertyChanged<TEntity>(this ObjectContext context, TEntity entityContainer, string propertyName)
            where TEntity : IEntityWithKey, IEntityWithRelationships
{
    bool isModified = false;
    EdmMember edmMember = GetEdmMember(context, entityContainer, propertyName);

    switch (edmMember.BuiltInTypeKind)
    {
        case BuiltInTypeKind.NavigationProperty: /*navigation property*/
                        {
                            NavigationProperty navigationProperty = edmMember as NavigationProperty;
                            IRelatedEnd sourceRelatedEnd = entityContainer.RelationshipManager.GetRelatedEnd(navigationProperty.RelationshipType.FullName,
                                                                                                             navigationProperty.ToEndMember.Name) as IRelatedEnd;
                            EntityState state = (EntityState.Added | EntityState.Deleted);
                            IEnumerable<IGrouping<IRelatedEnd, ObjectStateEntry>> relationshipGroups = GetRelationshipsByRelatedEnd(context, entityContainer, state);
                            foreach (var relationshipGroup in relationshipGroups)
                            {
                                IRelatedEnd targetRelatedEnd = (IRelatedEnd)relationshipGroup.Key;
                                if (targetRelatedEnd.IsEntityReference()
                                    && targetRelatedEnd.IsRelatedEndEqual(sourceRelatedEnd))
                                {
                                    isModified = true;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        } break;

        case BuiltInTypeKind.EdmProperty: /*scalar field*/
                        {
                            ObjectStateEntry containerStateEntry = null;
                            isModified = context.IsScalarPropertyModified(propertyName, entityContainer, out containerStateEntry);
                        } break;

        default:
                        {
                            throw new InvalidOperationException("Property type not supported");
                        }
    }

    return isModified;
}
```

and a method for scalar property changes tracking:

```
private static bool IsScalarPropertyModified(this ObjectContext context, string scalarPropertyName, IEntityWithKey entityContainer, out ObjectStateEntry containerStateEntry)
                {
                    bool isModified = false;
                    containerStateEntry = context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(entityContainer.EntityKey);
                    IEnumerable<string> modifiedProperties = containerStateEntry.GetModifiedProperties();

                    string changedProperty = modifiedProperties.FirstOrDefault(element => (element == scalarPropertyName));
                    isModified = (null != changedProperty);

                    if (isModified) 
                    {
                        object originalValue = containerStateEntry.OriginalValues[changedProperty];
                        object currentValue = containerStateEntry.CurrentValues[changedProperty];
                        //sometimes property can be treated as changed even though you set the same value it had before
                        isModified = !object.Equals(originalValue, currentValue);
                    }

                    return isModified;
                }
```

Tracking scalar properties is simple, right. When you have foreign keys included in your entities you may always check if those have been changed (make sure FK fields in your objects remain in sync with navigation properties, which is often an issue).
The navigation property case in the code above should give you an idea of implementation, well it should work in most cases.

PS. If you are working on implementation of audit system, interceptors introduced in EF 6.1 is what you may want to have a look at (just an idea)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj556606#Interceptors

Comment: Sorry, could you please explain what this code does and where I should be placing it in my app?

Comment: Hi Mike, I've updated the code, so that it is more clear now: IsPropertyChanged is designed as extension method for ObjectContext. Its usage is self-explanatory: `objectContextInstance.IsPropertyChanged(entityObject, "PropertyNameInEntityObject")`

Comment: From what I can see, Interceptors are still very crude in EF6.1. They give access to the SQL being generated for logging, but not to any other part of the pipeline and hence not to the actual entities.

Comment: That was just an idea, I'm not aware about details of the feature you try to implement. From what I've read in you question though, IsPropertyChanged implemented above is what you need - simply pass entity object instance and property name to the method, and it will return one of the boolean values - true, if property was changed and false if it wasn't

Comment: for example, `myEntitiesContext.IsPropertyChanged(employee, "OrganizationId")` or `myEntitiesContext.IsPropertyChanged(employee, "Organization")` will check if [OrganizationId] / [Organization] navigation property in Employee instance was changed

Comment: @MikeDymond, I've added `IsScalarPropertyModified` method so that now you have a complete solution. Copy all 3 methods to static class(extension methods can only be part of static class) and those will do the job...`IsScalarPropertyModified` works great, and `IsPropertyChanged`, like I said, needs testing

Comment: thanks for your input however what you are proposing doesn't really solve my problem. I need something much more generic, i.e. have any of the navigation properties on any of the Entities I am manipulating changed? If so what entity have they changed on, what are their new values and what was it set to before. I could use your code and some reflection to achieve something like this but the performance would not be great. What I have had to resort to instead is simply putting the FK Properties on the entities I want to audit and they get picked up and tracked by the change tracker.

Comment: `IEnumerable<EdmMember> edmMembers = entityType.MetadataProperties.First(p => p.Name == "Members").Value as IEnumerable<EdmMember>;` this will give the entire list of Entity members, you can iterate through this one. and check for changes in object state manager.

Comment: Or you can implement the partial methods that are added to you ObjectContext Entity's each property setter: i.e. Id property of Entity [Organization] will have following code behind its setter set
`if (_Id != value){ OnIdChanging(value); ReportPropertyChanging("Id"); _Id = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value);ReportPropertyChanged("Id");OnIdChanged();}`

Comment: Or you can edit the model code generation template(t4) and insert a custom method call in property setter generation something like `HandlePropertyChange<T>(string objectName, string property, T oldValue, T newValue)`. Implement custom cache of changes structure and work with it in HandlePropertyChange implementation  Ps.Sorry that I didn't get your scenario first time.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that tracking changes to the FK properties at the time you save changes is sufficient. After all, if I were doing this I would be interested in change in how one entity relates to another. Here's a really simple implementation of that which assumes that all FK properties end with "Id" and are integers.

```
foreach (var entry in context.ChangeTracker.Entries())
{
    foreach (var prop in entry.Entity.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        if (prop.Name.EndsWith("Id") && 
            !prop.PropertyType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(int)) && 
            context.Entry(entry.Entity).Property(prop.Name).IsModified)
        {
            // Log things like old value and new:
            var propEntry = context.Entry(entry.Entity).Property(prop.Name);
            var currentValue = propEntry.CurrentValue;
            var oldValue = propEntry.OriginalValue;
        }

    }
}
```